# Unix script to find specific variables and change third entry to new variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

```
function change {
  echo "Please enter the LAST name of the person: "
  read changelast
  echo "Please enter the FIRST name of the person: "
  read changefirst
  echo "Please enter the NEW phone number as XXX-XXX-XXXX: "
  read changephone
    while [[ "$changephone" != [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-
9] ]]
    do
   echo "Enter ONLY enter the phone number as XXX-XXX-XXX"
   read changephone
   done

}
```

I how do use the sed/egrep command in-order to check a file for the first and last name then change only the phonenumber?

Comment: Please omit everything from your script which is not necessary to describe the problem.

Comment: I did what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Set awk variables from the shell variables, then compare them to the columns in the awk script.

```
awk -v first="$changefirst" -v last="$changelast" -v phone="$changephone" \
    '$1 == first && $2 == last { $3 = phone }
     { print }' asg7phonebook > asg7phonebook.new
if cmp -s asg7phonebook.new asgphonebook
then echo "SORRY PERSON NOT FOUND...\n"
     rm asg7phonebook.new
else mv asg7phonebook.new asg7phonebook
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. i'll add that. Is my second while loop setup correclty?

Comment: Your second while loop was all wrong. This takes the place of the second while loop.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'll try it right now and see what happens.

Comment: I removed my second loop and replaced it was the awk command you suggested. I get an script[13]: asg7phonebook: cannot execute. I want to alert the user if the person is not found in my phonebook. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: See the addition to my answer. It checks whether `awk` changed anything, and prints the message if not.

Comment: I typed the code in but I get this: scriptTEMP[13]: asg7phonebook: cannot execute
usage: cmp [-l] [-s] file1 file2 [skip1] [skip2]

Comment: Fixed it, I forgot one of the filenames that it's comparing

Comment: I don't know where that first `cannot execute` error is coming from. That would happen if you have a line that begins with `asg7phonebook`, but there's nothing like that in my answer.

Comment: I edited my OP with the code you entered. I'm not getting any error codes but I am getting: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1. BTW, I would still to retain all the information that's currently in my phonebook. The command (asg7phonebook.new asg7phonebook) will purge the information in the current file, right?

Comment: No, this doesn't purge anything.

Comment: Sorry, my previous post should have said that I am getting two error codes: awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: I just tested the awk script, I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Did you copy the single quote at the end of the line that begins with `awk`?

Comment: I've tried to tweek the boolean condition but it still deletes absolutely everything from the phonebook and replaces it with the new entry. This command is what's doing it, I think: else mv asg7phonebook.new asg7phonebook. Is there a way to save all phonebook entries and just remove 1 entry?

Comment: I don't remove anything. The first line of the awk script replaces the phone number if the names match. The second line writes the current line, which is either the original line or the modified line.

Comment: Bud, the requirements (I was just told) are to use sed and/or egrep. awk is not allowed as part of the solution (which I initially started to figure out on my own). FML...

Comment: How can I reach the same solution except using SED and/or EGREP? I tried sed "s/$changelast/changefirst/g" asg7phonebook to search for the names. That seems to output results...

Comment: I give up. You just changed the entire question. The only way such a silly "requirement" makes sense is if this is homework, and I'm done doing your homework for you.

Comment: I agree. It is silly and I didn't know awk was not allowed so I initially started building around it. Thanks for your input otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

get old phone number in a variable as

```
OLD_NO=`cat phonebook | grep $changelast | grep $changefirst | awk '{print $3}'`
 then replace old with new no. as
sed -i 's/$OLD_NO/$changephone/' phonebook
```

Note: this will replace all the matching no., but since you are dealing with phone numbers so every person has unique phone number.